# How do we bulkify a trigger to create multiple @mention chatter feeditems?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-chatter

I came across this problem, and I think right now there is no way to bulkify a trigger and include multiple chatter feed items with @mention?

Comment: whats the solution for it